# Are symbols treat the same as letters in equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I'm wondering if anyone could help me here, there's a bunch of images going around the internet with [image] + [image] = [number]. Are images and symbols treat the same as letters in algebra?

For example:

[car] [car] = 9

xx = 9.

In my head simplifying these would be

[car]² = 9

x² = 9.

x and car would have the same value of 3 and treat the same.

iv'e picked the best answer as there's no obvious "correct" answer, however the two answers iv'e gotten is, i'm happy to keep hearing feedback on this, got to spend this quarantine some how.

The original 73 (Which is personally disagree with).

Or the 42.9041249358 which I got.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: So in my opinion this image **doesnt** equal 73 https://cdn.shortpixel.ai/client/q_lossy,ret_img,w_1278/https://gadgetgrasp.com/wp-content/uploads/p-guillelo-answer-1278x1536.jpg because the 4 brooms would be b + (b x b) + b = 12 **NOT** b + b + b + b = 12

Comment: It looks to me like the witch is $15$, the wand is $7$ and the broom is $4$ so we have $4+7\times15=109$.  (I only see $3$ brooms.)

Comment: 4 brooms, middle one is on top of one and another which would make it b + (b x b) + b following the laws of maths imo which would make brooms worth **2.60555127546**

Comment: @PaulSmith I also only see 3 brooms.

Comment: There's definitely 2, it's a stupid zoom in to notice Facebook meme image...

Comment: With a *puzzle*, notational conventions need not apply. Even explicit arithmetic symbols may represent non-obvious operations, at the whim of the puzzle-maker. With Facebook-meme puzzles, there are meta-considerations such as (1) the puzzle-maker may not be very good at designing puzzles (or could be mis-remembering something seen elsewhere), or (2) the puzzle-maker may have intentionally designed a nonsense puzzle in order to become "famous" for wasting people's time with an unsolvable task (like distributing a spot-the-differences puzzle with two identical images).

Comment: How do you interpret the image of the witch holding a broom and a wand? Is this the product of the individual elements, or their sum? This is significant, as the value of the witch without the accessories must be determined in order to solve the puzzle.

Comment: @Daniel that's a great point. I don't think the overlapping brooms representing multiplication is any more reasonable than the witch-broom-wand juxtaposition doing the same...

Comment: I think this is not a question about mathematics. It would be more appropriate on Puzzling SE.

Comment: Note that the (rather, "a") solution to the witch/broom/wand puzzle is explained [here (GadgetGrasp.com link)](https://gadgetgrasp.com/p-guillelo-answer/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I understand your question. The middle "broom" is really two brooms. Since these two brooms are effectively next to each other with no operation designated "between" them, you want to know if this should follow the notational convention that $ab = a \times b$.

The answer is, I have no idea. This question isn't about any kind of laws or rules of math, it's a question about what kind of notational convention we should apply, which is a matter of convenience of communication.

We choose to have $ab$ mean $a \times b$ because it's convenient, but that use is at our discretion and the context matters. Clearly, no one takes $33$ to mean $3 \times 3$.

The two adjacent brooms could be interpretted as the multiplication of "broom" with itself, or it could be interpretted as a separate symbol altogether that denotes two brooms. I think the latter is probably the intention.

In any case, this question can't really be answered. The matter is just notational convention and convenience of communication, which should be expected to break down and apply differently if someone goes out of their way to communicate something in such a weird way.

Comment: I like this answer, what you're saying is there's no definite answer to the question because the question is too vague to answer appropriately. Some people like myself would broom squared whereas some people may just add them thus getting two completely different answers.

Comment: The intention of your given picture is clearly not to have people come up with a definite answer but to start arguing.

Comment: It's from Facebook so yes 100%, however I don't mind a debate on answers, arguments are just unnecessary

Comment: I don't really think it's vague, I just think you've casted a slightly reasonable doubt. The intention is almost certainly that the middle symbol represents two brooms. I think your interpretation would be more much more common if the brooms were actually two separate brooms next to each other, not overlapping with the bottom one just barely visible. It's a stretch to call it multiplication as it's pictured.